# Displaying newly inserted item in CollectionView in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I have a user feed that I use a `CollectionView` to display. The `CollectionView` gets its data from an `ObservableCollection` in the corresponding `ViewModel`.

Once the user adds a new item, I do an `Insert` at index `0` which successfully adds the new item to the `CollectionView` but that item doesn't come into view unless I pull the items down in the `CollectionView`. As a matter of fact, I see no indication that a new item even exists at the top because the scroll bar remains at the top, giving no hint that there's another item right above the item that was first before the new item was inserted.

How do I make sure the newly added item gets displayed?

Here's the XAML code:

```
...
<CollectionView
   ItemsSource={Binding FeedItems}>
   ...
</CollectionView>
```

Here's the `ViewModel` code:

```
public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems { get; } = new();

[RelayCommand]
async Task AddItem(FeedItem newItem)
{
   FeedItems.Insert(0, newItem);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling ScrollTo?

Comment: Eventhough it's MVVM, because it's directly connected to your CollectionView, you may find that you get a better response if you were to run FeedItems.Insert() in the MainThread.

Comment: @Jason I tried `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"` to no avail. My question is how would I invoke `ScrollTo` once I add the new item to `CollectionView` because that takes place in the view model, not code behind.

Comment: @StephenQuan I tried handling the `Insert()` in `MainThread` but it still doesn't show or scroll to the new item. It looks as though the `CollectionView` needs some type of refresh and I'm not sure how to invoke that other than issuing `FeedItems.Clear()` which doesn't help in this case because I'd lose all the existing items in the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Your VM can raise an event your page responds to, or your page could even subscribe to the CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Because you're using `ObservableCollection` your `CollectionView` is suppose to get notified of changes such as `Insert()`. Because it isn't something isn't working, but, there is insufficient information to determine why. What happens if you were to call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FeedItems));` immediately after calling `FeedItems.Insert()` ?

Comment: So the `ObservableCollection` is getting updated. I think it’s just a scrolling issue which I’ve yet to come up with a solution for. I tried creating an event handler for `BindingContextChanged` for the `CollectionView` but adding a new item to the `ObservableCollection` doesn’t seem to trigger that event for the `CollectionView`. Trying to figure out how to implement what @Jason has suggested.

Comment: Use CollectionChanged, not BindingContextChanged.  See Peter’s answer for an example

Comment: @Sam for nothing but testing, can you tell me what happens, if you do this: base.OnCollectionChanged( new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)), after inserting the item at position 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MVVM many fear to access the ViewModel from the View. The purpose of MVVM pattern is to separate responisbility. So accessing the ViewModel for the purpose to manipulate the View controls is perfectly fine.

So, that said, if you want to use `ScrollTo`, that should to be done in the View and to get the event you can to access that through the ViewModel. Does that make sense?

In your Ctor add these lines of code and the added item in your CollectionView will be visable.

```cs
(BindingContext as MainViewModel ).FeedItems.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        int index = (BindingContext as MainViewModel ).FeedItems.IndexOf(e.NewItems[0] as FeedItem);
        MyCollection.ScrollTo(index, position: ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, animate: true);
    }
};
```

**Update**

When adding an item to indext 0, it scrolls to it

[image]

Comment: This works and doesn't work at the same time. Your code works perfectly and thank you for clarifying the logic I needed to understand for capturing `CollectionChanged` event. However, I still don't get the desired effect and I'm beginning to think this is a bug in .NET 8 RC2. I actually detect a tiny movement in the `CollectionView` as if it'll scroll down to show the new item but it doesn't. When I manually scroll down even ever so slightly, I see the new item. So it gets added to the `CollectionView` but for some reason `ScrollTo` is not doing its job. Thanks again for clear the explanation.

Comment: What if you change the `ScrollToPosition` to Center? `ScrollToPosition.Center`

Comment: I tried both `ScrollToPosition.Start` and `ScrollToPosition.Center` to no avail. Interestingly, if I set the `index` to 3, it does scroll to the item at `index` 3. One other strange thing I'm noticing is that when I manually scroll down ever so slightly, I see this "sticky" effect as if the `CollectionView` had snapped to the top item. BTW, I'm NOT using snap to position. I get the feeling that the `CollectionView` is thinking the item previously at `index` 0 is still at `index` 0 even though the newly inserted item is now at `index` 0.

Comment: Another observation is that if you look at the screen capture @StephenQuan shared in his answer, there's a refresh effect in the `CollectionView`. I'm not seeing that in mine. All I notice is this small upward movement in `CollectionView` items as if it's making an effort but there's no refresh effect. As I mentioned above, I get the feeling that the `CollectionView` is not quite updating properly and it's thinking the item previously at `index` 0 is still at the top.

Comment: When I add an Item to the top of the list, it works. Look at my update in my answer. Is this what you are after?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve but in my case it's not scrolling to the top of the list. What version of .NET is your .NET MAUI app targeting? Mine is .NET 8 RC2.

Comment: If I use @StephenQuan's approach, it actually works. As in his screen capture, it actually completely refreshes the `CollectionView`. Initially, I felt his approach was a bit too much because there's a built-in `CollectionChanged` event so I thought creating my own event was unnecessary but it does work. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What he is doing is the same as far as I can see, except that he is using his own Eventhandler, which is fine but no need when there is a perfectly "good" one to use. Strangly the CollectionView update is better, considering both solutions use ScrollTo. Perhaps remove animation? What I am wondering also is if we can use margins and set a -10 to the top and see what happens to your top item.  Also you should file an issue to the MAUI team.

Answer (score 2):

I made changes to your ViewModel.

- 1. I changed the signature of AddItem so that the argument is now FeedItem (it appears you've already made this change too)
- 2. I added an `ScrollRequested` event handler

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public event EventHandler<int> ScrollRequested;
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems { get; } = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task AddItem(FeedItem newItem)
    {
        FeedItems.Insert(0, newItem);
        ScrollRequested?.Invoke(this, 0);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task AddRandomItem()
    {
        await AddItem(new FeedItem() { Title = $"Item {rnd.Next()}" });
    }
}
```

I created a mock `FeedItem` class:

```cs
public class FeedItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In the `MainPage.xaml.cs` code behind, I hook up to the EventHandler so I can update the scroll:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainViewModel VM;
    public MainPage(MainViewModel VM)
    {
        this.VM = VM;
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
        VM.ScrollRequested += VM_ScrollRequested;
    }

    ~MainPage()
    {
        VM.ScrollRequested -= VM_ScrollRequested;
    }

    private void VM_ScrollRequested(object sender, int index)
    {
        collectionView.ScrollTo(index);
    }
}
```

To test, I wire up to a simple `Grid` so that I can see the scroll working:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:FeedItem">
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Add Random Item" Command="{Binding AddRandomItemCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: AddItem.gif]

A full working example of the above can be found here: https://github.com/stephenquan/StackOverflow.Maui/tree/main/StackOverflow.Maui.Mvvm.AddItem

Comment: I don’t believe it’s necessary to set an `ObservableCollection` as an `ObservableProperty`. Aren’t they already designed to call `INotifyPropertyChanged`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: Ok, I replaced the code so that it now matches yours so it still works. So we have ruled out the `ObservableProperty`. What do you think about my other comment regarding `FeedItem` vs `MyItem` ?

Comment: Sam is right. Observable collection is indeed observable. No need of this private field, that is annotated to be made as a property.

Comment: @H.A.H. thanks, but, let's move away from talking about FeedItems `ObservableProperty`. We've established that this is not the problem already, to stop further discussion, the answer now reflects Sam's version.

Comment: I have seen it. It is perfect.

Comment: @Sam I've updated the answer to reflect how you can add an event handler to your view model so that you can consume it in your MainPage code behind and scroll your CollectionView and keeping the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @StephenQuan you have very strange way of coding. Very unusual. Yet you made it work. I have learned new thing today from your code.

Comment: @StephenQuan I thought it was unnecessary to create my own event because there's already a built-in `CollectionChanged` event but for some reason using that is not producing the desired result while yours does. I still feel using the `CollectionChanged` event makes more sense but like @H.A.H., I too learned from your code. I'm upvoting your answer. Thank you for all the effort you put into it.

Comment: @Sam if you can make `CollectionChanged` work, that would be preferred. In my own projects, I found it to be quite natural to add event handlers to my view models. I didn't think it was something out of the ordinary.

Comment: @StephenQuan Adding an event handler to the `ViewModel` definitely seems like a pretty useful approach and in this case it's producing the desired results, though I have no idea why `CollectionChanged` is not producing the same results. Thanks again for your help!